# SQL access query to count and delete rows > n

Tags: ms-access

Can someone help me with a SQL (Access) query to delete all rows greater than n entries ordered by ID?

I.e. say I have 1200 rows of data with ID incremented . I need delete the first amount leaving only  200.

If I have only 199 rows of data, then I need to preserve them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to a working copy of MS Access to test this but what you might be looking for is this:

```
delete * from table_name where ID not in(
select top 200 ID from table_name order by id desc
);
```

Comment: Access requires `DELETE * FROM xxx` syntax.

Comment: Amended to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks that worked just had to remove ( ) around the 200

Comment: Amended to also reflect that, sorry for not being able to syntax check it myself.